# Bigquery SQL: Calculate the average recency and latency of customer transactions by month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate monthly averages of - customer recency (days since last order) and customer latency (days between last order and previous order).

Calculating recency on the last day of each reporting month.

Including customers in the monthly calculation where:

- max(order_date) is BETWEEN reporting mth_end_date (i.e. not in future) and 12 months prior.
- latency for the max(order_date) IS NOT NULL (i.e. it has a prior order)

Below is my progress to date using sample data.

**EDIT: Updated query below now works for an individual month, but not across a range of dates.
I can't figure out how to join the date array and also use it in the calculations.**

The values for Dec-2021 are (showing workings):

[image]

```
With input_data AS (

SELECT '#1238' as order_id, DATE('2021-12-15') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 18 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1201' as order_id, DATE('2021-10-10') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 18 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1198' as order_id, DATE('2021-07-05') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 20 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1134' as order_id, DATE('2020-10-15') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 10 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1112' as order_id, DATE('2019-08-10') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 5 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1234' as order_id, DATE('2021-07-05') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 118 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1294' as order_id, DATE('2021-01-05') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 68 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1290' as order_id, DATE('2021-01-01') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 82 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1284' as order_id, DATE('2020-01-15') as order_date, 'c22222' as cust_id, 98 as order_value),

-- date array that I'm trying to use to group by in final step but not used yet
dates AS (
  SELECT
   LAST_DAY(array_date, month) AS mth_end_date
  FROM 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY( 
      (SELECT MIN(order_date) FROM input_data), 
      (SELECT MAX(order_date) FROM input_data), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as array_date),

-- for each order record add the date of that customers prior order
-- exclude all orders in the future (relative to the report date)
enhanced_orders AS (
SELECT 
*
,lag(order_date) OVER (PARTITION by cust_id ORDER BY order_date) AS cust_prev_order_date
FROM input_data
WHERE order_date < Date('2021-12-31')),

-- for each customer determine the most recent, and the next most recent, order dates  
cust_calc as (
SELECT
cust_id
, max(order_date) as max_order_date
, max(cust_prev_order_date) as max_prev_order_date
FROM enhanced_orders
GROUP by 1),

-- for each customer calculate how many days ago their most recent order was from the report date, 
-- and calculate the days between their last two most recent orders
-- exclude customers if their most recent order was >12m ago, or they don't have an order prior to their most recent one
cust_calc2 AS (
SELECT
cust_id
, date_diff(Date('2021-12-31'),  max_order_date, day) as recency
, date_diff(max_order_date, max_prev_order_date, day) as latency
FROM cust_calc
WHERE max_prev_order_date IS NOT NULL 
AND max_order_date > date_sub(Date('2021-12-31'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))

-- average the recency and latency of all customers at the report date
SELECT
avg(recency) AS monthly_recency
,avg(latency) AS monthly_latency
FROM cust_calc2
```

Comment: Reformulated the second part of question which is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71137629/how-do-i-reference-a-date-array-in-multiple-ctes/71140270#71140270 Thanks to Jon Armstrong!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudo-code that I think will help:

```
with allorders as (
    select *, lag(orderdate) over (order by orderdate) as lastorderdate
    from T
    -- this is probably more efficient
    where orderdate between <one year ago> and <end of current month>
        and exists (
            select 1 from T t2 
            -- this query isn't restricted by the one-year range
            where t2.customerid = T.customerid and t2.orderdate < T.orderdate
        )        
)
select customerid, avg(<difference in lastorderdate and orderdate>)
from allorders
group by customerid
```

This ought to work but it might be slow:

```
with recentorders as (
    select *, lag(orderdate) over (order by orderdate) as lastorderdate
    from T
)
select customerid, avg(<difference in lastorderdate and orderdate>)
from recentorders
where orderdate between <one year ago> and <end of current month>
    and lastorderdate is not null
group by customerid
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn I will give this a go

Comment: Edited question with updated query. It working for a specified month but not across the date array.

Comment: Obviously you can't hard-code a date that doesn't apply across the entire query. Try grouping on month plus year in your `calc2` cte.