# How do I reference a date array in multiple CTE's?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a working query that calculates summary metrics based on customer transactions up to the end of that month (using the last day of the month in the calculations).

I am now trying to run these calculations against all months in the file.

I have two CTE's that refer to the reporting month, and I have not been able to figure out how and where to join the date array to the query.

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Working query below with a month-end date hard-coded into query.

```
With input_data AS (

SELECT '#1238' as order_id, DATE('2021-12-15') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 18 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1201' as order_id, DATE('2021-10-10') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 18 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1198' as order_id, DATE('2021-07-05') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 20 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1134' as order_id, DATE('2020-10-15') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 10 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1112' as order_id, DATE('2019-08-10') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 5 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1234' as order_id, DATE('2021-07-05') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 118 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1294' as order_id, DATE('2021-01-05') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 68 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1290' as order_id, DATE('2021-01-01') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 82 as order_value
UNION ALL SELECT '#1284' as order_id, DATE('2020-01-15') as order_date, 'c22222' as cust_id, 98 as order_value),

-- date array that I'm trying to use to group by in final step but not used yet
dates AS (
  SELECT
   LAST_DAY(array_date, month) AS mth_end_date
  FROM 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY( 
      (SELECT MIN(order_date) FROM input_data), 
      (SELECT MAX(order_date) FROM input_data), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as array_date),

-- for each order record add the date of that customers prior order
-- exclude all orders in the future (relative to the report date)
enhanced_orders AS (
SELECT 
*
,lag(order_date) OVER (PARTITION by cust_id ORDER BY order_date) AS cust_prev_order_date
FROM input_data
WHERE order_date < Date('2021-12-31')),

-- for each customer determine the most recent, and the next most recent, order dates  
cust_calc as (
SELECT
cust_id
, max(order_date) as max_order_date
, max(cust_prev_order_date) as max_prev_order_date
FROM enhanced_orders
GROUP by 1),

-- for each customer calculate how many days ago their most recent order was from the report date, 
-- and calculate the days between their last two most recent orders
-- exclude customers if their most recent order was >12m ago, or they don't have an order prior to their most recent one
cust_calc2 AS (
SELECT
cust_id
, date_diff(Date('2021-12-31'),  max_order_date, day) as recency
, date_diff(max_order_date, max_prev_order_date, day) as latency
FROM cust_calc
WHERE max_prev_order_date IS NOT NULL 
AND max_order_date > date_sub(Date('2021-12-31'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))

-- average the recency and latency of all customers at the report date
SELECT
--- add in format_date('%Y-%m', eom_date)
avg(recency) AS monthly_recency
,avg(latency) AS monthly_latency
FROM cust_calc2 
-- Group by 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is based on tests with PostgreSQL 14. But the suggested changes should be directly applicable.

The result for just the months in the data:

[image]

[The PG 14 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2a78b8695917e490a200733bcff5d323)

Calculate the prior order date over all input_data, without restriction.  We'll add that restriction later:

```sql
   , enhanced_orders AS (
       -- for each order record add the date of that customers prior order
       SELECT *
            , lag(order_date) OVER (PARTITION by cust_id ORDER BY order_date) AS cust_prev_order_date
         FROM input_data
     )
```

Now introduce the list of report dates (implied cross join), and restrict rows based on each corresponding mth_end_date, adding the mth_end_date in the GROUP BY terms:

```sql
   , cust_calc as (
       -- for each customer determine the most recent, and the next most recent, order dates
       -- exclude all orders in the future (relative to the report date)
       SELECT cust_id
            , mth_end_date
            , max(order_date)           as max_order_date
            , max(cust_prev_order_date) as max_prev_order_date
         FROM enhanced_orders, dates
        WHERE order_date < mth_end_date
        GROUP BY 1, 2
     )
```

Include mth_end_date, as needed in the following term. Added an alias for eom_date.

Note: Some slight changes made for PG.  Just focus on the mth_end_date adjustments:

```sql
   , cust_calc2 AS (
       -- for each customer calculate how many days ago their most recent order was from the report date, 
       -- and calculate the days between their last two most recent orders
       -- exclude customers if their most recent order was >12m ago, or they don't have an order prior to their most recent one
       SELECT cust_id
            , mth_end_date AS eom_date
            , age(mth_end_date,   max_order_date)      as recency
            , age(max_order_date, max_prev_order_date) as latency
         FROM cust_calc
        WHERE max_prev_order_date IS NOT NULL 
          AND max_order_date > (mth_end_date - INTERVAL '1' YEAR)
     )
```

Finally, the last query expression groups by eom_date:

```sql
-- average the recency and latency of all customers at the report date
-- add in format_date('%Y-%m', eom_date)
SELECT eom_date
     , avg(recency) AS monthly_recency
     , avg(latency) AS monthly_latency
  FROM cust_calc2 
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY eom_date
;
```

The final PG SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_day(date)
RETURNS date AS
$$
  SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;

With RECURSIVE input_data AS (
       SELECT '#1238' as order_id, DATE('2021-12-15') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 18 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1201' as order_id, DATE('2021-10-10') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 18 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1198' as order_id, DATE('2021-07-05') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 20 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1134' as order_id, DATE('2020-10-15') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 10 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1112' as order_id, DATE('2019-08-10') as order_date, 'c12345' as cust_id, 5 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1234' as order_id, DATE('2021-07-05') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 118 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1294' as order_id, DATE('2021-01-05') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 68 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1290' as order_id, DATE('2021-01-01') as order_date, 'c11111' as cust_id, 82 as order_value UNION ALL
       SELECT '#1284' as order_id, DATE('2020-01-15') as order_date, 'c22222' as cust_id, 98 as order_value
     )
   , dates AS (
       -- date array to use to group by in final step
       SELECT DISTINCT LAST_DAY(order_date::DATE) AS mth_end_date
         FROM input_data
     )
   , enhanced_orders AS (
       -- for each order record add the date of that customers prior order
       SELECT *
            , lag(order_date) OVER (PARTITION by cust_id ORDER BY order_date) AS cust_prev_order_date
         FROM input_data
     )
   , cust_calc as (
       -- for each customer determine the most recent, and the next most recent, order dates
       -- exclude all orders in the future (relative to the report date)
       SELECT cust_id
            , mth_end_date
            , max(order_date)           as max_order_date
            , max(cust_prev_order_date) as max_prev_order_date
         FROM enhanced_orders, dates
        WHERE order_date < mth_end_date
        GROUP BY 1, 2
     )
   , cust_calc2 AS (
       -- for each customer calculate how many days ago their most recent order was from the report date, 
       -- and calculate the days between their last two most recent orders
       -- exclude customers if their most recent order was >12m ago, or they don't have an order prior to their most recent one
       SELECT cust_id
            , mth_end_date AS eom_date
            , age(mth_end_date,   max_order_date)      as recency
            , age(max_order_date, max_prev_order_date) as latency
         FROM cust_calc
        WHERE max_prev_order_date IS NOT NULL 
          AND max_order_date > (mth_end_date - INTERVAL '1' YEAR)
     )
-- average the recency and latency of all customers at the report date
-- add in format_date('%Y-%m', eom_date)
SELECT eom_date
     , avg(recency) AS monthly_recency
     , avg(latency) AS monthly_latency
  FROM cust_calc2 
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY eom_date
;
```

Comment: I'm not certain the monthly latency is calculated correctly.  I assumed the original SQL in the question handled that correctly.  That might need to be reviewed.

Comment: Thanks Jon - really appreciate your efforts on this one. Works fine in BQ with minor tweaks.

Comment: I calculated out the sample dataset by hand and the latency is correct. It is/ should be the avg of most the recent latency values (not say avg. of average latency). Thank you again!